# Angular-UI bootstrap timepicker validation fails

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I am using the timepicker directive from Angular-UI (http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

The example on their website works well, but when I use it in my project, the validation only works well when both, hour and minutes values are less than 10. When any value is equal or greater than 10, the validation fails. The time 11:45 should still be valid.

Example:

```
09:05 (ok)
09:15 (fails)
10:00 (fails)
11:45 (fails)
```

The validation fails due to maxlength. For example when I have 10:00 PM, the input classes are the following:

form-control text-center ng-animate ng-dirty ng-invalid **ng-invalid-maxlength** ng-touched

The timepicker directive usage:

```
<timepicker ng-model="repair.due.time" hour-step="1" minute-step="15" show-meridian="timepicker.showMeridian"></timepicker>
```

repair.due.time is a Date object and timepicker.showMeridian is true.

Can someone help me find a solution? The error is also reported here - https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2402

Comment: Seems like [danjac](https://github.com/danjac) found a workaround in the issue you linked ;)

Comment: I found a solution too, overridded the original directive of timepicker. But that's a temporary solution, until bootstrap ui gets updated.

Comment: You should share your workaround to help others in the same case ;)